# Can I keep my RSA keys when I reinstall Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, security, rsa

I want to install Ubuntu 11.10. Is there any way to keep my current RSA keys?

Comment: You could just move them to ~/.ssh, you may have to make the directory.

Comment: @Rob So I could just copy them to an external drive, do the install, then copy them back?

Comment: yup make sure to grab the public and private parts.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, easily. Simply copy the `~/.ssh` directory onto an external drive, perform the install, then copy them back.

Answer (score 0):

When you reinstall Ubuntu you can keep your home folder, with ALL your settings, files, etc.

Just don't format any partitions and your /home will be kept.

In particular, your private authentication keys are preserved.